# How to make a MovieClip change to get lighter or darker?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to have a movie clip in your flash game and when something happens (such as a mouse hovering over it) for it to become lighter or darker?

```
MovieClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onContact);

public function onContact(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     //Not Sure What To Put Here
}
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance,

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every object that has a colorTransform has the ability to manipulate it's colour.
For example try this:

```
public function onContact(contact:MouseEvent):void
{
    var displayObject:DisplayObject = contact.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
    displayObject.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform( .3, .3, .3); // makes object darker
}
```

Also, it's common to use tweening engines like TweenLite/TweenMax (http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) to tween the colorTransform. If you'll navigate to the provided link there is a plug-in explorer that allows you to test and experiment with different tweening plug-ins including Color Transform.

Comment: Must I import any Flash files to get this command to work? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: You will need at to import DisplayObject and ColorTransform classes.
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;